# Executing sbt in command line via python script and outputting to file

Tags: scala, python-2.7, sbt, subprocess, stdout

I have a set of json files in directory `/Desktop/jsons`, and I have a Scala script which takes in a json and outputs stuff. I can run it manually in the terminal by `cd`ing into the directory of the Scala script (`/Me/dev/scalastuff`) and running

`sbt --error "run /Desktop/jsons/jsonExample.json"`,

which outputs the stuff I want in the terminal.

I want to write a Python script which does this automatically and additionally outputs a json file with the "stuff" thats outputted by the Scala script.

My issues right now are using subprocessing. When I try to run

`BASEDIR = '/Me/dev/scalastuff'
p = subprocess.Popen(['sbt --error "run /Desktop/jsons/jsonExample.json"'], cwd = BASEDIR, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.stdout.read()
print out`

I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I'm completely stumped as to why this is occurring. I'm new to subprocess, so be light on me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`popen` in python takes a list of shell arguments. You're passing only one!

So it's trying to execute a file named wholly `'sbt --error "run /Me/Desktop/jsons/jsonExample.json"'`.

Obviously, this doesn't work.

If you use `popen`; only pass a simple array -- you needn't care about escaping:

```
subprocess.popen(['sbt', '--error', 'run /Me/Desktop/...'], cwd = BASEDIR, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Ah! That's surely what I was missing. Thanks so much -- I'll mark the question as answered once the time passes to allow it.